# How to use Python OpenID Connect module with IBM Cloud App ID?

Tags: python, authentication, ibm-cloud, openid-connect, ibm-appid

I signed up for [IBM Cloud App ID](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/about.html#about) to protect access to my cloud application. There is a sample that shows that the service can be used with Python. However, I want to use one of the (standard) OpenID Connect modules. How can I configure, e.g., [Flask-pyoidc](https://github.com/zamzterz/flask-pyoidc) to work with App ID? It requires a couple of parameters and I am unsure how they relate to what App ID provides.

```
provider_config = {
    'issuer': 'https://op.example.com',
    'authorization_endpoint': 'https://op.example.com/authorize',
    'token_endpoint': 'https://op.example.com/token',
    'userinfo_endpoint': 'https://op.example.com/userinfo'
}
auth = OIDCAuthentication(provider_configuration_info=provider_config)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the `provider_config` can be configured.

```
provider_config={
     "issuer": "appid-oauth.ng.bluemix.net",
     "authorization_endpoint": appIDInfo['oauthServerUrl']+"/authorization",
     "token_endpoint": appIDInfo['oauthServerUrl']+"/token",
     "userinfo_endpoint": appIDInfo['profilesUrl']+"/api/v1/attributes",
     "jwks_uri": appIDInfo['oauthServerUrl']+"/publickeys"
}
```

`appIDInfo` is either obtained from the Cloud Foundry environment on IBM Cloud or can be configured manually with a structure like the following:

```
"AppID": {
     "clientId": "your App ID client Id",
     "managementUrl": "https://appid-management.ng.bluemix.net/management/v4/-----tenantID----",
     "oauthServerUrl": "https://appid-oauth.ng.bluemix.net/oauth/v3/-----tenantID----",
     "profilesUrl": "https://appid-profiles.ng.bluemix.net",
     "secret": "the App ID secret",
     "tenantId": "-----tenantID----",
     "version": 3
}
```

The `clientId` and `secret` would then be used to populate the `client_info` object required by Flask-pyoidc. I have [sample code using Flask-pyoidc with App ID in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/data-henrik/github-traffic-stats). It shows all the steps from the configuration to using the decorators to protect the app routes in Flask.

Comment: Nice.  Any plans to capture how this would work with tornado?

Comment: I haven't used Tornado so far, but I could take a look for some other tutorials.

Comment: No worries.  I will take a look myself when I get a chance.  I really liked tornado, unlike flask it’s quite opinionated which helps a lot if you don’t use it all of the time.  There’s a great book [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/introduction-to-tornado/9781449312787/) and I created a cloud foundry tornado hello world [here](https://github.com/snowch/cf-tornado-hello-world)